# Can I import contacts without syncing?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I don't have a mobile, my laptops rarely leave home, but occasionally I would like to make a file available to myself (or someone else) away from home. Hence my foray into Ubuntu One.

My address book rarely changes, so I really need little in the way of syncing, but I do want to add a bunch of my contacts to my cloud so that they are available to me elsewhere. All I wish to do is export contacts from my home computer and import them to my cloud using LDIF or csv files rather than re-typing 60+ addresses or installing yet another full e-mail client (Evolution) just to get addresses into my cloud. Suggestions?

Comment: -?- -?- -?- O.o???

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to do this, honestly, would be to install Evolution, import your CSV file into the "CouchDB" addressbook, and then uninstall Evolution. You don't need to keep Evolution on your machine once you've got the contacts into the cloud, so you're basically using Evolution as a "contacts importer" application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but all you need to do is export from your mail program to a file, save it in your Ubuntu One folder, and import it on the other system.