# How do I import contacts from csv file into Ubuntu Contacts

Tags: contacts

My contacts are currently on my computer on CSV format. Is there any way to transfer them to  Ubuntu Contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/18363/10581).

> The quickest way to do this, honestly, would be to install Evolution, import your CSV file into the "CouchDB" addressbook, and then uninstall Evolution. You don't need to keep Evolution on your machine once you've got the contacts into the cloud, so you're basically using Evolution as a "contacts importer" application.